# Google Search Ads Price Automation Script

Tags: google-contacts-api

I want price to be shown on ads, price is constantly changing on site and I want prices to automatically change in the ads

currently, we're updating price manually for 20k products

So far its been manual work, I want it automated. I have over 20k product ads set up